# Can I allow my app to create Issues on my private GitHub repo?

Tags: git, github, github-api, issue-tracking

I want my app X to be able to create issues on the private repo Y for app X.

Basically in app X I want to create an input form similar to that of the new issue form on GitHub. Where there's a title, comment, and just labels.

Is there an API out there that will allow me to do this?

Comment: Yes, it appears so. https://developer.github.com/v3/issues/#create-an-issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use official github api for creating issues via any app. [Here](https://developer.github.com/v3/issues/#create-an-issue) is a link to the github issues api. Below is an example.

> POST /repos/:owner/:repo/issues

You have to include parameters required for creating issues like title, body, assignees etc.

Also you have check [github oauth flow](https://developer.github.com/apps/building-integrations/setting-up-and-registering-oauth-apps/) for github api since you are creating issues in private repository